# Integrate Stripe into qt mobile application

Tags: c++, qt, stripe-payments

I have a requirement of integrate stripe into Qt Mobile application for android and ios. I searched on it but not able to find any suitable starting point. What are the possible solutions for me to integrate stripe in c++ applications.

Answer (score 2):

So far there is no C++ API kit for Stripe.

All you can do by yourself from scratch.

1. Use `curl` to for Stripe API call.
2. Use a `json` c++ library for serialize/deserialize request/response.

Comment: I will go with this approach. https://forum.qt.io/topic/83860/integrate-stripe-into-qt-mobile-application/2

Comment: Good to go with this one

Comment: you should not recommend this approach. All API requests (except tokenization) require your Secret API key. You should never have this key in a mobile application as anyone would be able to access it and then use it as if they are you. You should always have a server to make all of those API requests. The only thing you do in a mobile application is tokenization.